# Adding Facebook Apps to Page Tabs

Tags: facebook, facebook-page

I have googled and googled around for this and found the blog post from Facebook about remove app profile pages etc. I also found that you can go to this link:

```
https://www.facebook.com/dialog/pagetab?app_id=[ID NUMBER HERE]&display=popup&next=[URL OF YOUR DOMAIN]
```

The problem is what do i put in URL OF YOUR DOMAIN. I cant put a site url in the app settings because its not a web site application, its a page tab application. Any combo of URL's i try, it just errors with "URL not owned by application"

Any ideas or experiences with this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to register the URL first with Facebook and then use it. First go to http://developers.facebook.com. Then go to your app and hit [Edit App]. At the Basic Info section, you'll find a textbox requesting you to enter the APP Domain. Once you save it will work fine.

I simply entered www.my-domain.com, no http, no slashes.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the response. For some reason, i cant fill this in without filling in the website URL.

Comment: Yes, you are right actually... here you have to use full URL format `http://www.my-domain.com`

Answer (score 1):

Use `FB.ui` method of JS-SDK with method `pagetab` as shown in example of [Add Page Tab Dialog documentation](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/add_to_page/) this will automatically provide needed info to dialog.

```
FB.ui({method: 'pagetab'}, function(){
  // User either closed dialog or added tab, you can call Graph API to check...
});
```

Comment: there you have to specify the redirect_url... so nothing new here

Comment: @decebal, it is not needed if you use `FB.ui`, JS-SDK will provide one automatically and fully transparent to you and will trigger an event once needed...